# Gulp webpack load jquery only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, gulp

I've got two Gulp tasks in my gulpfile.js. It's used for a website.

The first one compiles with webpack the main js file, used on all pages of the site (mainly visuals), and combines it to a single file.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
let firstBuildReady = false;

function done(err, stats) {
    firstBuildReady = true;
    if (err) { // hard error, see https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html#error-handling
        return;  // emit('error', err) in webpack-stream
    }
    gulplog[stats.hasErrors() ? 'error' : 'info'](stats.toString({
        colors: true
    }));
}

let options = {
    output: {
        publicPath: '/js/',
        filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].js' : '[name]-[chunkhash:10].js'
    },
    watch:   isDevelopment,
    devtool: isDevelopment ? 'cheap-module-inline-source-map' : false,
    module:  {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            //include: path.join(__dirname, "app/src/scripts/modules"),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ["env"]
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    ]
};

if (!isDevelopment) {
    options.plugins.push(new AssetsPlugin({
        filename: 'scripts.json',
        path:     __dirname + '/app/manifest',
        processOutput(assets) {
            for (let key in assets) {
                assets[key + '.js'] = assets[key].js.slice(options.output.publicPath.length);
                delete assets[key];
            }
            return JSON.stringify(assets);
        }
    }));
}

return gulp.src(jsSRC)
    .pipe(plumber({
        errorHandler: notify.onError(err => ({
            title:   'Scripts',
            message: err.message
        }))
    }))
    .pipe(named(function(file){
        return 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(webpackStream(options, null, done))
    .pipe(gulpIf(!isDevelopment, uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDIST))
    .on('data', function() {
        if (firstBuildReady) {
            callback();
        }
    });
```

});

The second one compiles each js module as a single file - some js scripts, used on special pages. These scripts are included only there where needed.

```
gulp.task('webpack', function(callback) {
let firstBuildReady = false;

function done(err, stats) {
    firstBuildReady = true;
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    gulplog[stats.hasErrors() ? 'error' : 'info'](stats.toString({
        colors: true
    }));
}

let options = {
    output: {
        publicPath: '/js/',
        filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].js' : '[name]-[chunkhash:10].js'
    },
    watch:   isDevelopment,
    devtool: isDevelopment ? 'cheap-module-inline-source-map' : false,
    module:  {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ["env"]
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};

if (!isDevelopment) {
    options.plugins.push(new AssetsPlugin({
        filename: 'webpack.json',
        path:     __dirname + '/app/manifest',
        processOutput(assets) {
            for (let key in assets) {
                assets[key + '.js'] = assets[key].js.slice(options.output.publicPath.length);
                delete assets[key];
            }
            return JSON.stringify(assets);
        }
    }));
}

return gulp.src('app/src/scripts/modules/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber({
        errorHandler: notify.onError(err => ({
            title:   'Webpack',
            message: err.message
        }))
    }))
    .pipe(named())
    .pipe(webpackStream(options, null, done))
    .pipe(gulpIf(!isDevelopment, uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDIST))
    .on('data', function() {
        if (firstBuildReady) {
            callback();
        }
    });
```

});

But I have to include Jquery in every single file for the second task, otherwise it's not compiled. But Jquery is included in the main app.js file.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you wanting to load these webpack bundles at runtime? I'm curious why you're not using the typical Webpack approach of entry points & code splitting.

Comment: I've written a plugin for my cms, it inserts only the needed scripts into html using manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're using a somewhat exotic way of loading JS in your application (instead of approaches like `require.ensure`), your easiest option may be to use [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) when building your individual modules. Your main script/page will have to ensure that jQuery is globally exposed (like under `window.$` or `window.jQuery`). Then, for your webpack config, include something like this:

```
{
  // ...
  externals: {
    jquery: '$'
  }
}
```

This will substitute `$` for all `require('jquery')` calls instead of including `jquery` in each JS bundle.